# POST property with XML tag is replaced to a <div> in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I post my model to the controller with a property that contains a XML tag like <web.config>, it's a div in the controller, why? (in the browser's devtools the postdata is still correct)

The property in view:

```
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "DataConfig")]
    public string DataConfig { get; set; }
```

The controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyModel data)
    {

        //Here data.DataConfig contains the <div> instead of <web.config>

        return Redirect("myRedirct");
    }
```

I want to post plain text with random tags like f.e, this is the TextAreaFor in the view:
[image]

Notice the formdata:
[image]

And the result, two divs..
[image]

Comment: I have add the screenshot in my post

Comment: it is not  what we want. Please share a simple code in controller what you do?

Comment: That is not helpful at all - there could be a <div> in the bit I can't see.

Comment: Simple code is shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the issue was but this seems a workaround for me:

```
model.DataConfig = this.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated.Form["DataConfig"];
```